# Google Sheets - Embedded arrays with multiple columns under each other

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to insert 2 column wide fields under each other. I tried with embedded arrays but was not successful.
So basically from:

```
a    1     e    5
b    2     f    6
c    3
```

I would like to get:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
e    5
f    6
```

I tried with 
={{A:A,B:B};{C:C,D:D}}
but could not get it working, however
={{A:A,B:B},{C:C,D:D}}
put the columns the same as they were so its intresting that with ; its not working.
The blocks are always 2 column wide but the rows are different length

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=filter({A:B;C:D},{A:A;C:C}<>"")
```

This will return rows where Columns A or C are not blank.

Answer (score 0):

Just under `c` assuming `a` is in A1:

```
=ArrayFormula(C1:D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find a clean built-in formulaic solution to this one that doesn't utilize some sort of built-in magic auto expansion (like [pnuts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53713624/2799848)). Here is my approach using `OFFSET` that will also work in Microsoft Excel.

In two columns, copy this formula.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-ROW($G$1))/2,IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($G$1),2)=1,2,0))
```

In the second column, modify the formula, adding 1 to the column offset parameter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-ROW($G$1))/2,1+IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($G$1),2)=1,2,0))
```

where `$A$1` is replaced with the address of the top left of your range and `$G$1` is the starting location of your output range. This should be resistant to auto-update of formulas from range insertions and deletions <sub>(which I despise butchering my formulae and conditional formatting rules)</sub> by using only the bare number of references, which are all absolute.

This works by dividing the row offset from your starting position by 2 and rounding down (via an implicit cast to integer when used as a parameter to the `OFFSET` function) to get the row number of your input range. Then it shifts over 2 columns on every odd row to get data from the second column pair.

Note this is not a size-aware function, so it interweaves the second column pair:

```
a    1
e    5
b    2
f    6
c    3
```